# Wordpress Upload media isuue Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I had a previously working wordpress and recently I updated it to version 4.7.2. But now i can't see my media files.

When I try to upload an image following error popups.

> "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached,
>   aborting! in C:\wamp64\www*\wp-includes\cache.php on line 724 "

Please find the code in cache.php(line number 724,725,726)

```
protected function _exists( $key, $group ) { 
return isset( $this->cache[
$group ] ) && ( isset( $this->cache[ $group ][ $key ] ) ||
array_key_exists( $key, $this->cache[ $group ] ) );     
}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Preetham Hegde.

Comment: are you using `php_xdebug` ?

Comment: From which wordpress version have you updated to latest?

Comment: wordpress Version 3.4.1

Comment: @PreethamHegde you ever get this fixed? I'm sitting on the same issue now, have increased the nesting level on xdebug to 512 and still getting the issue. I'm getting it on propriety code though, nothing to do with Wordpress, but the issue only came up when I added an isset() check to an if statement...

Comment: I got the same error with `wp-cli` and the command `wp i18n make-pot` when I wanted to create the POT file to translate a WordPress plugin. I removed `php-xdebug` package on Linux to fix the problem. I also read you can increase the limit of `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in the `php.ini` file.

Answer (score -3):

You could try to wiggle down the nesting by implementing parallel workers (like in cluster computing) instead of increasing the number of nesting function calls.

For example: you define a limited number of slots (eg. 100) and monitor the number of "workers" assigned to each/some of them. If any slots become free, you put the waiting workers "in them".